# p2app application to ask for administrator rights

Tags: macos, pyqt, py2app

I have created a python script that helps automate a part of my work on Mac Os VMs.
In addition to that it makes use of some other files (some jsons and a few files that need to be copied on the Macos machine in a specific location).
Since the script contains also a ui part(via pyqt) I need to pack all files into one app, but I ran into an issue
I need the resulting app to ask for Administrative rights when it is ran. I search the internet and the py2app documentation and can't find any info on how to achieve this

any workaround or py2app is not what I need?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: edited the post. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using "elevate" library.
worked like a charm :)